# Does PyDev has auto completion feature as the one in R-Studio?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, pydev

I am trying to configure the Preference in PyDev in Eclipse for facilitating coding Python. What I want to get is, just like in R-Studio, press tab to select the method or class I want and let the editor auto-complete it. Is that possible and how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Well, PyDev is consistent with Eclipse, so, it uses Ctrl+Space/Enter to request completions and apply them (and you can have completions 'always on' by going to preferences > pydev > editor > code completion > request completion on all letter chars).

Also, make sure you read http://pydev.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/mastering-writing-code-on-pydev.html to help you on the bindings...